# Broken Samsung TV, power LED remains on in standby, TV has no power

Tags: power-supply

I have a Samsung TV which will not turn on. The power LED remains on when plugged in, pressing the power button results in the LED flicking off before returning to constantly on. I have tried the recommended hot fixes all to no avail and decided that it is likely a power board/ logic board issue. I am a relative beginner but I am determined to learn where the issue might lie and how to go about repairing the TV myself.

It seems that the issue is often with capacitors however they all appear to be in good stead. The voltage measurements taken from my multimeter also dont appear to signal any obvious issues.

1. If I were to go about debugging, what is a checklist I should follow using my multimeter and
2. what values am I looking for?

Moreover,

Could it be that it the issue lies not with the circuitry but with something else? Perhaps as a result of transport in a car?

There is also a *ticking* sound coming from the power board when plugged into the mains? Is this usual? Sorry if that is a really uneducated question.

I can provide voltage readings if necessary, the Ps on pin going from the power to the logic reads 25 AC and 12 DC, what sort of reading should i be looking for here, I’m in the UK and as I understand it my readings may different to American electronics.

Very keen to learn so any input would be greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Ticking usually means there is a short circuit and the power supply repeatedly tries to start but shuts down due to overcurrent situation.

Comment: Sounds like a capacitor to me. You need an ESR meter to measure the caps. a multimeter is not useful for this measurement. A schematic is helpful. There’s two, maybe three power supply sections on that pcb. You need to determine which one is upset.

Comment: @kartman This is a LED backlighted LCD panel, its supply board hasn't a high-voltage section, so, the power supply has only two sections. I think that only cold-cathode LCD TV´s and monitors has a third power supply section.

Comment: I would check those capacitors in the "COLD" section of the power supply: two pairs of bigger capacitors, and a fifth little one. But definitely you will need to measure the ESR of the capacitors. If one of them is responsible for the fault, probably it's because its ESR has become too high, and not because they lost their capacitance. If you have no way of measuring their ESR, **maybe** just replacing those four capacitors with newer ones could solve the failure. It is not the "perfect solution", but it is feasible to try.

Comment: The photos you added to the question are good, but please understand that even the best photos are not enough to us help you in a effective way. And please be aware that EE.StackExchange is not a forum for asking for generic advice about repairing.

Comment: The power supply section has a PFC section and a main switcher. Optionally there may be a standby supply. On the black 450V electro, you should be able to measure around 360-380V. If thereis only around 320V, the PFC is not working. The ticking could be caused by an overload/short circuit on the outputs but also from a faulty electro in the high voltage section used to power the electronics. This might only be a small 47uF 50V unit. A schematic would help here.

Comment: Note - a quick google found a repair kit of 8 components. That suggests there is a common fault. I see a small electro (as i mentioned previously) and a blue high voltage disk capacitor from the snubber section which I‘ve found failed on a couple of TVs I’ve fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Recently had my first and only TV to fix, it was a hisense, but the internal layout is pretty similar (not that there is much going on there).

Usually when you have a TV the thing number one to do is to check if it's no backlight or no image. In dark room (not totally dark, just lights off and preferably away from windows) and with a flashlight you can check if there actually is a picture on the screen. With damaged backlight circuit or backlight power supply circuit, you will still have image, which usually will not be visible, unless specifically looking for it.

Also, as I was turning the TV on while it was face down, through the back plate of the TV (it has holes here and there) I noticed my backlight actually flashed on for like a quarter of a second and then went dead. I'm not saying it will help, but it's something you should pay attention to when working with TV without image. First you check and rule out the most basic, as usual.

Your situation looks different tho. Clicking sound in the power supply board does indeed suggest that the problem occurs when the power board tries to, well, power the stuff, and then something goes bad. Looks like a short circuit somewhere. There are two equally possible options:

1. Problem on the supply board itself
2. Problem on whatever it's powering

Recommendation on the further steps:

1. Unpower the thing and let it sit for 5-10 minutes. Some caps can be charged with high voltage. Overall, when working with power board, just touch it on the sides and stay away from any high voltage parts whenever possible. I was nervous I would destroy my scope when I had to probe 170V for the backlight, but it ended up ok. Still was really nervous.
2. Disconnect the backlight from the power supply, try to turn it on and see if the clicks are still there.
3. You can get a TV backlight tester for 10 bucks or so. It's called exactly like that. You can connect backlight to it and see if it turns backlight on. You can even turn on the TV but power the backlight from the tester, you are supposed to see the picture.
   3b. Before you get a tester, you can at least test backlight for the short circuit with multimeter. If backlight + and - beep together. It is highly unlikely given LED configuration (several LEDs need to burn through for this to happen; I can't really imagine it, but since it's 1 minute test, just do it).
4. My (inexperienced with TV but experienced with laptops) bet is that the problem is most likely on the power board. These power boards cost 20$, it's a lot safer and easier to replace the whole thing, it doesn't cost much and it saves a lot of time.

Personally, I think it's a short on a power supply and I would replace the power supply board. Of course, you can wait for caps to discharge and try to do some beeping to ground with the multimeter just to make sure the short is really there (again, you can disconnect stuff and test the "powered" boards  for short too, just the main power lines, no need to check every capacitor in the country).

Don't kill yourself, I still want your upvote.

Comment: thanks for that, I’ve ordered some replacement capacitors, simply to get some practical experience, I’m not hopeful that this will fix the issue but at least i know i can buy a replacement power board. Just finally where is +- situated so that i can test the backlights? Cheers

Comment: Backlight + and - are located on the power board, backlight has its own cable (warning: 150V+ circuit). It is the cable that powers...well, not other boards. Instead goes directly into the TV itself. To power the backlight LED. Hard to miss. All other power cables power other boards.